# javascript document.createTextNode Returns <p>&nbsp;</p> in java scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I want to show a message in element in page of wordpress(if parameter "message" in url have a value ).for this purpose i installed "Header and Footer Scripts" plugin.and write this code in "insert script to ":

```
<script>
function getUrlParameter(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
    var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
    var results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
};
if(getUrlParameter('message'))
{
const para = document.createElement("p");
const node = document.createTextNode(getUrlParameter('message'));
para.appendChild(node);

const element = document.getElementsByClassName("entry-content");

document.querySelectorAll('.entry-content').forEach(element => {
    element.appendChild(para);
})

}
</script>
```

but when I inspected ,I saw that there is a

> `<p>`

tag that is filled with "&nbsp".
even if I set the value to "OK", the output will still be the same.

Comment: Is there more than one `.entry-content` element? If no, you should be using querySelector, if yes, you have more issues.

Comment: So what does `getUrlParameter('message')` return?

Comment: Modern JavaScript. `const qs = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search); const message = qs.get('message');` No reg exp needed

Comment: no, i only one "entry-content" element.How to use querySelector??

Comment: getUrlParameter('message') return a persian text example : ثبت%20انجام%20شد

Answer (score 0):

I used embed code plugin instead of "Header and Footer Scripts" plugin in word press.My problem was solved.

```
<script>
const qs = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search); 
const message = qs.get('message'); 

if(message )
{
const para = document.createElement("div");

const element = document.getElementsByClassName("entry-content");
para.setAttribute("id", "Div1");
document.querySelectorAll('.entry-content').forEach(element => {
    element.appendChild(para);
    
});
para.style.backgroundColor ="#d4edda";
para.style.color="#155724";
para.style.bordercolor= "#c3e6cb";
para.style.padding=".75rem 1.25rem";
para.style.borderradius=".25rem";
para.textContent=message;
}
</script>
```